# How to make an enemy face a character

Tags: c#, xna

Hey guys ive got this problem where i just can't get my enemy to rotate towards my character 
ive been trying for days and have asked around but nothing and so it would be awsome if you could give me some ideas.

this is my enemy class now in this code here everything works fine it does what i want however it faces the mouse and not my character

```
class Class1
    {
         Character character = new Character();
         EnemyShip blah = new EnemyShip();

        Texture2D texture;
        Rectangle rectangle;

        public Vector2 origin;
        public Vector2 velocity;
        public Vector2 position;
        float rotation;
        const float forwardvelocity = 1f;
        float friction = 0.1f;

        public Vector2 distance;


        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Ships/WarShip");
            position = new Vector2(800, 300);
        }




        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            distance.X = mouse.X - position.X; //  these two line are the one i want to 
            distance.Y = mouse.Y - position.Y; // change however when i change mouse.X to //say character.Position.X my enemy ship moves towards the top left corner of the screen //and not the character

            rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);

            position = velocity + position;

            velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * forwardvelocity;
            velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * forwardvelocity;

            rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
            origin = new Vector2(rectangle.Width / 2, rectangle.Height / 2);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }
    }
    }
```

And this is my Character class

```
class Character
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public float angle = 0;
        public Vector2 velocity;
        public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        public float forwardvelocity = 5;
        public float friction = 0.03f;
        public Vector2 origin;

        public Rectangle sourcerectangle;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Ships/charactership");

        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Position += velocity;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(angle ) * forwardvelocity;
                velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(angle) * forwardvelocity;
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                velocity.X = -(float)Math.Cos(angle) * forwardvelocity;
                velocity.Y = -(float)Math.Sin(angle) * forwardvelocity;
            }
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) angle -= 0.05f;

                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) angle += 0.05f;

                else if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
                {
                    float i = velocity.X;
                    float j = velocity.Y;

                    velocity.X = i -= friction * i;
                    velocity.Y = j -= friction * j;
                }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------

        }



        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {

             sourcerectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture.Width, texture.Height);
            origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, sourcerectangle, Color.White, angle, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: "character.Position.X [...] towards the top left corner" - seems like the characters position is 0/0. Now why is that? Are you sure, the character is moved correctly? Are you sure you're checking the position of the right character object? Set a breakpoint on those two commented lines and check if the expected character position matches the actual position.

Comment: Can I suggest that you use matrices rather than angles. It will make the transition to a 3D system much easier, avoids potential Euler angle problems and the performance would be better than using atan2, sin and cos. Matrices work just as well in 2D (3x3) as they do in 3D (4x4)

Comment: Thanks for the advice ill try to implement it in my next project

Answer (score 5):

I notice you have a `Character` variable in your `Class1`. It is set to `new Character()` *but then nothing else is ever done with it ever*. I'm guessing this means your *actual* `Character` is within your `Game` somewhere, and this other `Character` in this `Class1` *is a completely different variable entirely*. So naturally, using its `Position` is meaningless.

Since your enemy **depends** on the `Character` variable for its own computations, **pass in the dependency:**

```
public void Update(Character c, GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    distance.X = c.Position.X - position.X;
    distance.Y = c.Position.Y - position.Y;
...
```

Then in the top level `Game` or what not:

```
//your actual character
Character c;
...
//in Game.Update
c.Update(gameTime);
c1.Update(c, gameTime);
```

Then you can simply remove that `Character character = new Character();` in `Class1`, as it is useless.

There are "lazier" methods such as singletons and other `static`ness-related methods, but I don't recommend these.

Comment: Scott I don't have words to express how thankful i am i feel like an idiot(I am) for missing something so simple as putting my characters update in my enemys class I guess i just assumed updating it in my game1 waas enough. Thanks a Bunch

Comment: Not a problem. If this solved your problem go ahead and "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "Class1" is your enemy class...

```
class Class1
{
     Character character = new Character();
     EnemyShip blah = new EnemyShip();
```

Instanciate the character inside your enemy class makes no sense,  I think you are not referencing the right character instance in your enemy class.

Seems that the character variable inside your enemy class is never updated, what can be the reason it is always at (0,0)